# OData Query With Angular 2

Tags: rest, angular, odata

In angular 1.x, we had an option to use "query" method of `$resource` to write OData queries communicating with web api. For example `$filter`, `$orderby` etc. I am playing with Angular 2 RC1 and was wondering about how to write OData queries in angular 2 along with web api. Is there a way to do this in angular 2?

Comment: There is nothing like `$resource` yet for Angular2 AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

angular2-odata

The project is in an early and untested stage at the moment. The goal is to create a fluent API for querying, creating, updating and deleting OData resources in Angular2. OData service for Angular

See https://github.com/gallayl/angular2-odata
and
https://github.com/StefH/angular-odata-es5

Answer (score 0):

there's a command line tool which grabs the odata Metadata.xml and generates strongly typed Typescript models from entities, complex types, etc... and services from OData entity sets and custom functions / actions. It also has the same fluent API for $query, $expand, $top, $skip, etc... as [angular2-odata](https://github.com/gallayl/angular2-odata)

Please check [ODataTypescriptServiceGenerator](https://github.com/gallayl/FuryTech.OdataTypescriptServiceGenerator)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my integration of OData with Angular 2. Look at the service it is very easy to integrate    https://github.com/Artur93gev/ODataService-Angular-v4

Comment: Please, provide your answer with code example, regarding to users question. Otherwise It looks like an advertising of your service and nothing else

Comment: you want me to copy past the Readme file??

Comment: Not the whole Readme, but some appropriate example would be just in place, I think.